# No visible @interface for NSURL declares the selector componentsseparatedbystring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

The NSArray declaration brings up an error because "no visible @interface for NSURL declares the selector componentsseparatedbytring".

```
NSURL *MyURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                 URLForResource: @"artList" withExtension:@"txt"];
NSArray *lines = [MyURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; // each line, adjust character for line endings

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSString *line;
    //in lines;
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"line: %@", line]);
    _wordDefBox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_wordDefBox.text, lines];
}
```

Comment: `componentsSeparatedByString:` is a `NSString` method, not a `NSURL` one. I guess what you want is: `+stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` , then use `componentsSeparatedByString:` on it.

Answer (score 2):

You missed a step. Once you have the URL, you need to load the file into an `NSString`. Then call `componentsSeparatedByString` on the `NSString`.

```
NSURL *myURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                 URLForResource: @"artList" withExtension:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
// Use the appropriate encoding for your file
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (string) {
    NSArray *lines = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    // and the rest
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to load string from %@: %@", myURL, error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general when you see such an error it means **class** X( here `NSURL`)  doesn't have *any* **method** named Y ( e.g. `componentsseparatedbystring`) or at least it doesn't have it in its *interface* ie it's not it's public method, it may be it's private method and available to its *implementation*. Always try to make sense of what the compiler is telling you. To find out more you can 'Cmmd + click' on any class and it will take you to it's interface and you can see what public methods it has. Try that on `NSString` and `NSURL`

Here specifically : `NSURL` doesn't have that method. It doesn't belong to `NSURL`, it belongs `NSString`.